# Select con valor vacío al llenarlo por segunda vez

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Tengo estos 2 Select en un componente.html hijo.

Desde el componente.ts del padre lleno la información de los Select que están en un service del hijo.

```js
//En un service.ts tengo definido esto:
infoFlujo : InfoFlujos = {
  categorias   : [],
  subcategorias: [],
  .
  .
};

export interface InfoFlujos {
  categorias   : Select[];
  subcategorias: Select[];
  .
  .
}

export interface Select {
  idx : string,
  desc: string
}

//En el componente.ts Padre
//Está el método getSubcategoria() voy a un servicio por la información y a esa información la mapeo para poder agregarla a mi Select de esta manera.

getSubcategoria( idCat : string){
.
.//Mando llamar a mi servicio y me regresa las subcategorías en subcategoriasResp.jsonResponse
.
const subcategoriasParse : any = JSON.parse(subcategoriasResp.jsonResponse);

this.infoFlujoService.infoFlujo.subcategorias = subcategoriasParse.listCatalogCatSub.map( (subcategoria : any) => {
    return { idx : subcategoria.subCategoryID, desc : subcategoria.descSubCategory };
});
}
```

```html
<!-- Componente html hijo -->

<select class="form-control" id="categoria" formControlName="categoria" (change)="getSubcategoria(categorias.value)" #categorias>
    <option selected disabled value="">SELECCIONE UNA CATEGORÍA</option>
    <option *ngFor="let categoria of infoFlujoService.infoFlujo.categorias" [value]="categoria.idx">
            {{categoria.desc}}
    </option>
</select>
                                            
<select class="form-control" id="subcategoria" formControlName="subcategoria" #subcategorias>
    <option selected disabled value="">SELECCIONE UNA SUBCATEGORÍA</option>
    <option *ngFor="let subcategoria of infoFlujoService.infoFlujo.subcategorias" [value]="subcategoria.idx">
            {{subcategoria.desc}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Las categorías se llenan con el onInit(), y la primera vez que selecciono una categoría se llena correctamente la subcategoría:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si al seleccionar una subcategoría, después cambio la categoría al llenar nuevamente las subcategorías deja en blanco el Select con la información normal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como lo estoy llenando

```
this.infoFlujoService.infoFlujo.subcategorias = subcategoriasParse.listCatalogCatSub.map( (subcategoria : any) => {
    return { idx : subcategoria.subCategoryID, desc : subcategoria.descSubCategory };
});
```

Comment: Y como es tu metodo getSubcategoria(categorias.value) exactamente

Comment: Ya modifiqué la información, el método getSubcategoria(), va a un servicio y regresa la información y esa información es la que le hago el .map()

Comment: Intenta esto <option selected disabled value="seleciona una subcategoria">SELECCIONE UNA SUBCATEGORÍA</option>
o puedes probar con placeholder="seleciona una subcategoria"

Comment: Lo intenté pero de principio sin cargar nada ya me aparece en blanco el Select :(

Answer (score 0):

El motivo más probable por el que se queda en blanco el campo subcategoría es que tenga asignado un valor que no existe en las `option` del `select`.

Así que para solucionar esto, dentro del método llamado `getSubcategoria` que se ejecuta al cambiar la categoría principal se necesita limpiar los valores que pudiera tener el campo subcategoría, una forma de conseguir esto es:

```
this.aquiNombreDelFormulario.get('subcategoria').reset('');
```